# .NET 5.0 Failed to scaffolding razorpage on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-5

I'm follow .net 5 documentation
but I'm having a problem when I was tried to scaffold my model using this command:

`dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages/Movies --referenceScriptLibraries`

the error message looks like the following image:
[image]

I was tried some action to fixed this issue:

1. rebuild the project using `dotnet build`
2. reinstall package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`
3. create new project `dotnet new webapp -o MyWebApp`
4. Install package that I follow from several tutorial on internet

But there is no action that fixed my problem.
When I check `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator -h` it returns a message like the following image:
[image]
the error said **there is no code generator in my project**
So, I think this like the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package not installed properly.
So I also tried to downgrade the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` version.
But it still doesn't work.

The following image is my latest `.csproj` file detail:
[image]

By the way I'am working on

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Visual studio code 1.51.1 (latest vscode for now)
- .NET 5 SDK's

Can you please help me, guys?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi guys. FYI, I was installed and ran .NET 5 SDK's with Latest Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 OS. And surprisingly, there is no problem with the scaffolding feature. It's works normally. But I still looking for solution on ubuntu OS. Hopefully it help if you have same problem with me guys

Comment: Hi guys. FYI It's work now,  with newest version of .NET sdk's. Thanks all